# How to place two hyperlinks next to each other?

Tags: html, css

```css
.tabs {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tab {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 -18px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-box {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff inset;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  /*-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);*/
}

.tab.active {
  /*z-index: 40;*/
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.tab.active .tab-box {
  background-color: #F1F1EB;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #fff inset;
  height: 60px;
}

.mail {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px text-indent: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab active">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab report">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="mail">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#q_modal">Questions</a>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#h_modal">Help</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

In the example above I have tab elements and two hyperlinks on the right side. I would like Questions and Help two show next two each other. Current code is pushing them in the next row. How to fix this problem with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of the `width: 40px` property on `.mail` they should float next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove width or make it larger than 40px under .mail class or ..

Try adding `display: flex;` to the .mail class.
Also, look at this css tricks. It can be super helpful when working with css flexbox. 
[Css Tricks - Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Afterwards you just need to add padding or margin to space them out.

```css
.tabs {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tab {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 -18px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-box {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff inset;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  /*-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);*/
}

.tab.active {
  /*z-index: 40;*/
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.tab.active .tab-box {
  background-color: #F1F1EB;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #fff inset;
  height: 60px;
}

.mail {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px text-indent: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab active">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab report">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-box">
      <span>Tab 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="mail">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#q_modal">Questions</a>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#h_modal">Help</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works in this case, I'm not quite sure this is the right answer for this in general- the container is still smaller than the contents, and the width should be determined by the contents.  The content here is just text, and automatically inlines next to each other with no extra styles

Comment: @amethystx87 You're right in that sense, but if they end up wanting to add other child elements flex can help resolve the issue along with your suggestion. Thanks for letting me know.